# Why Is My Wordpress Theme Losing CSS On Mobile?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, viewport

I'm working on a Wordpress theme over at http://mbgb.co.uk/blog

Up in-till an hour ago all was OK, now however whenever accessing the site with mobile dimensions, the previous CSS has disappeared. I've tried going back to previous CSS but that's not working and to my knowledge I've not touched any other part of the build.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it only in mobile or in desktop too?

Comment: Desktop is fine, just mobile, site loses CSS styles at 768px, above that and this problem does not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the url you mentioned. 
Found some weird tags. 
Please open your website and view your page source(Ctrl + U).
Preferably in Mozilla Firfox. As there the errors will be highlighted.
Please see the attached screenshots.
Go through the page source and resolve the things that are making these occur.

[Please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNcFW.png)
[Please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMcSQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if there are css rules that make your CSS appear only for desktop screens? This could be only explainable reason.

Comment: I have cannot find anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just left a tag out - one day I'll learn not to panic. Sorry guys.